# angularjs using HTML5 telerik_ReportViewer

Tags: angularjs, html, telerik-reporting

Trying to use telerik_ReportViewer in my angular application. Can this be accomplish in a directive?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#reportViewer1")
        .telerik_ReportViewer({
            serviceUrl: "/api/reports/",
            templateUrl: '/ReportViewer/templates/telerikReportViewerTemplate-8.1.14.618.htmll', 
            reportSource: { 
                report: "Telerik.Reporting.Examples.CSharp.ProductCatalog, CSharp.ReportLibrary",
                parameters: {
                    CultureID: "en"
                }
            }
        });
</script>
```

would like to pass on $scope variables to the reports reportsSource and parameters.

This is currently my controller and it works but its a hack.

```
angular.module('AppReport').controller('reportviewerController', ['$scope','$location',
function ($scope, $location) {

    $scope.ReportName = 'Default.trdx';

    $scope.$on('ReportName', function(ev, data) {
        if(ev.targetScope == $scope) return;
        $scope.ReportName = data.Report;
        $scope.ReportViewChange();
    });

    $scope.ReportView = function (name){
        $("#reportViewer1")
            .telerik_ReportViewer({
                serviceUrl: "http://localhost/Reporting.API/api/reports/",
                templateUrl: '../content/templates/telerikReportViewerTemplate-9.0.15.324.html',
                reportSource: {
                    'report':  $scope.ReportName,
                    'parameterValues':{ DocumentNumber : ''}
                }
            });
        }
    $scope.ReportViewChange = function() {
        var viewer = $("#reportViewer1").data("telerik_ReportViewer");
        viewer.reportSource({
            'report': $scope.ReportName,
            'parameterValues': {DocumentNumber: ''}
        });
        viewer.refreshReport();
    }

}])
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrapped my in a directive.  Still a bit hacky but until Telerik release a more pure angular version of the report viewer probably best you can do.

```
function report($compile) {

    var linker = function (scope, element, attrs) {

        $('#ReportViewer1').telerik_ReportViewer(
            {
                error: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                },
                reportSource: {
                    report: 'Reports.blankReport, Reports'
                },
                serviceUrl: '/api/reports/',
                templateUrl: '/ReportViewer/templates/telerikReportViewerTemplate-9.0.15.324.html',
                ready: function () {
                    this.refreshReport();
                }
            });
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'app/directives/Report/template.html',
        link: linker,
        scope: {
            content: '=',
            reportname: '@reportname'
        }

    };
}

var app = angular.module('timebanking').directive("report", report);
```

**Template**

```
<div id="ReportViewer1"  style="height: 900px;"> </div>
```

**Usage**

```
 <report reportname="'blankreport'"></report>
```

Comment: Thx Kevin , going to test this its cleaner than my solution. Will let you know how it turns out.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an updated version which actually accepts the different reports. The only thing I could not get working is changing the report.  I could pass in a new report name and refresh the report viewer but it would stay on the same report.

```
   var reportoptions = function (reportname) {
      //  alert(reportname);

        return {
            error: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            reportSource: {
                report: 'Reports.' + reportname + ', Reports'
            },
            serviceUrl: '/api/reports/',
            templateUrl: '/ReportViewer/templates/telerikReportViewerTemplate-9.0.15.324.html',
            ready: function () {
                this.refreshReport();
            }
        }
    }

    var linker = function (scope, element, attrs) {
        $('#ReportViewer1').telerik_ReportViewer(reportoptions(attrs.reportname));
    };


    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'app/directives/Report/template.html',
        link: linker,
        scope: {
            content: '=',
            reportname: '@reportname'
        }

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Kevin solution, you can add a watcher to the reportName property to update the datasource and refresh the report

```
var reportNameWatcher = scope.$watch("reportName", updateReport);
var reportParametersWatcher = scope.$watch("reportParameters", updateReport);

function updateReport(newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal !== oldVal) {
         report.reportSource({
             report: 'Reports.' + scope.reportName + ', Reports',
             parameters: scope.reportParameters
         });
         report.refreshReport();
     }
}

element.on('$destroy', function () {
   reportNameWatcher();
   reportParametersWatcher();
});
```

Just take the report object from jQuery

```
var report = $('#ReportViewer1').telerik_ReportViewer(reportoptions(attrs.reportname)).data("telerik_ReportViewer");
```

Hope it helps.

---

My complete directive:

```
function Report() {

        function Link(scope, element, attrs) {

            var report = null;

            function createReportOptions() {
                return {
                    error: function (e, data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    reportSource: {
                        report: 'Reports.' + scope.reportName + ', Reports',
                        parameters: scope.reportParameters
                    },
                    serviceUrl: '/api/reports/',
                    templateUrl: '/ReportViewer/templates/telerikReportViewerTemplate-9.0.15.324.html',
                    ready: function () {
                        this.refreshReport();
                    }
                }
            }

            function createReport() {
                report = element.telerik_ReportViewer(createReportOptions()).data("telerik_ReportViewer");
            }

            createReport();

            var reportNameWatcher = scope.$watch("reportName", updateReport);
            var reportParametersWatcher = scope.$watch("reportParameters", updateReport);

            function updateReport(newVal, oldVal) {
                if (newVal !== oldVal) {
                    report.reportSource({
                        report: 'Reports.' + scope.reportName + ', Reports',
                        parameters: scope.reportParameters
                    });
                    report.refreshReport();
                }
            }

            element.on('$destroy', function () {
                reportNameWatcher();
                reportParametersWatcher();
            });
        }

        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                reportName: '@',
                reportParameters: '='
            },
            link: Link
        }
    }
```